# How to render 3d object to silhouette image in python?

Tags: python, renderer

I am trying to render an obj (a human body model) to its corresponding silhouette image given camera intrinsic&&extrinsic parameters and I want to know which renderer is suitable for the task. I don't want real time display of the rendered images because efficiency is my top concern. I have 100000 3d objects and i need to write a script to render the silhouette images of those objects in one go.

Comment: Try [ModernGL](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) you can render directly to an image.

Comment: Here is [Headless rendering example](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/Headless-rendering-with-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example rendering with OpenGL to an image using [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL) and [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow)

- [pillow docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io)
- [ModernGL docs](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io)

Sample code:

```
import struct

import ModernGL
from PIL import Image

ctx = ModernGL.create_standalone_context()

prog = ctx.program([
    ctx.vertex_shader('''
        #version 330
        in vec2 vert;
        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(vert, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    '''),
    ctx.fragment_shader('''
        #version 330
        out vec4 color;
        void main() {
            color = vec4(0.3, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    '''),
])

vbo = ctx.buffer(struct.pack('6f', 0.0, 0.8, -0.6, -0.8, 0.6, -0.8))
vao = ctx.simple_vertex_array(prog, vbo, ['vert'])

fbo = ctx.framebuffer(ctx.renderbuffer((512, 512)))

fbo.use()
ctx.viewport = (0, 0, 512, 512)
ctx.clear(0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
vao.render()

pixels = fbo.read(components=3, alignment=1)
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', fbo.size, pixels).transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
img.show()
```

Comment: Here is an example using 3D [perspective and lookat matrices](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/blob/master/examples/GLWindow/05_perspective_projection.py#L25). I reccommend using some sort of GLM for matrix manipulation rather then hardcoding it in the shader.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into ModernGL for my task.

Comment: Is using EBO supported  in ModernGL? I cannot find the usage of EBO in the doc you provided.

Comment: It is called [IBO](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/blob/master/examples/PyQt5/untitled.py#L48) and it works with 32bit integers (-1 is the primitive restart index)

Comment: I am referring to the element-buffer-object in gl, but i believe ibo and ebo are the same thing (doesn't really matter)... Another thing I don't see any tutorials on the ModernGL doc site, are you planning to include some step-by-step tutorials for GL beginners like me?

Comment: link an example of an EBO you need, I am pretty sure the index_buffer parameter of the [vertex_array](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Context.html#ModernGL.Context.vertex_array) does the same thing.

Comment: I am planning to add tutorials and examples, I just uploaded an [example](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/blob/master/examples/PyQt5/untitled.py) for ibo.